# Get closest parent with stated attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code :

```
<input pid="hidVoteKey" type="hidden" value="0" />
    <ul id="mainPostList" class="verticalList">
        @foreach (var postViewModel in Model.Posts)
        {
            <li><div class="voteCon">...</div></li>
        }
    </ul>
```

Then I have a jquery that loop all elements with class voteCon and then try to get the parent input like this :

```
$(".voteCon").each(function () {
     InitVoteControl($(this), $(this).parent("input[pid='hidVoteKey']").val());
 });
```

The problem is that it will not find the hiddenfield?

In this case the voteCon contains up/down buttons and there is some javascript functions bound here to make ajax calls. There will be multiple lists like the one above on the same page but thay all will have diffrent hidVoteKey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't find the `<input>` because it **isn't** a parent (or ancestor) of the `<div class="voteCon">`. It's on the same level as (a sibling of) the `<ul>`, which is an ancestor of the `<div>`. You could do this:

```
$(this).closest('ul').prev('input[pid="hidVoteKey"]').val()
```

Comment: Thanks! That works great but the problem is that sometimes there will not be a ul? Is there anyway to just find the first parent of the voteCon element that have pid="hidVoteKey"?

Comment: @Ivy Like I said, the `<input>` and the `<div class="voteCon">` aren't linked in that way. There isn't any ancestor (parent is only up one level so not the correct term) of the `.voteCon` element that has `pid="hidVoteKey"`.

Comment: Okay, so what I need is to place a wrapper around the top voteCon in the above example the ul element and then use this wrapper in your suggested code to be able to get the hidVoteKey?

Comment: @Ivy That would work, though you'd want to change the `.prev()` call to `.find()` (or `.children()`).

Comment: Is this the best solution? Will it help to do as @ncn corp suggested to change the field to not be hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Just use then not type hidden , you can use inline style="display:none;"